# Как отсортировать объектный массив по разным ключам(JavaScript)?

Tags: javascript, массивы

Есть массив с разными ключами:

```
{B: {A: 1, C: 1}, A: {B: 1, C: 3}, C: {A: 3, B: 1}}
```

Нужно отсортировать по первым ключам(они разные), то есть

```
{A: {B: 1, C: 3}, B: {A: 1, C: 1}, C: {A: 3, B: 1}}
```

Это возможно сделать?

Comment: "Это возможно сделать?" --- Да!

Comment: @ https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/191482/%d0%90%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d0%a8%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b9 are.sort() is not is not a function, is not undefined

Comment: а, тут объект. не увидел

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как отсортировать по массиву в правильно порядку ключи в объекте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1196745/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d1%82%d1%81%d0%be%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d1%83-%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8f%d0%b4%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b5)

Comment: @AlexeyTen там числа, а тут - буквы

Comment: Без разницы. Смысл в том, что не нужно сортировать объекты. Если важен порядок, то надо использовать массивы.

Comment: Любая функция может изменить этот порядок, потому что никто его не учитывает. Так что вы добьётесь только временного порядка для какого-то сиюминутного использования.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let obj = {B: {A: 1, C: 1}, A: {B: 1, C: 3}, C: {A: 3, B: 1}}

let sortedObj = Object.entries(obj)
  .sort()
  .reduce( (o,[k,v]) => (o[k]=v,o), {} );
  
console.log(sortedObj);
```