# Отсортировать объект

Tags: javascript

Мне нужно отсортировать объект. Как это сделать? Можно на чистом JS, или еще Lodash использую (там тоже не нашел ничего подходящего).

У меня есть массив с ключами: `['a', 'b', 'c']` и объект `{b: 1, c: 2, a: 3}`. Хочу получить на выходе `{a: 3, b: 1, c: 2}`. Единственное что в голову приходит - превратить объект в массив массивов пар ключ-значение, отсортировать функцией `sort` и снова собрать в объект. Но это какое-то такое себе решение...

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как отсортировать по массиву в правильно порядку ключи в объекте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1196745/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d1%82%d1%81%d0%be%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d1%83-%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8f%d0%b4%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b5)

Answer (score 1):

Вроде и так работает

```js
        const oldObject = { b: 1, c: 2, a: 3 }
        let newObject = {};
        ['a', 'b', 'c'].forEach(item => {
            newObject[item]=oldObject[item]
        })
```

Comment: Там есть кнопочка "выполнить код". Ошибка же.

Comment: Но в целом идея ясна. Тоже норм вариант

Comment: забыл поставить точку с запятой)

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение, может кому пригодится:

```js
const flip = collection => {
  const result = {}
  
  for (const key in collection) {
    result[collection[key]] = key
  }
  
  return result
}

const sortObjectByKeys = (obj, comparator = null) => Object.keys(obj).sort(comparator).reduce((acc, key) => {
  acc[key] = obj[key]
  return acc
}, {})

const keys = ['a', 'b', 'c']
const keysInverted = flip(keys)
const obj = {b: 1, c: 2, a: 3}
console.log(sortObjectByKeys(obj, (l, r) => keysInverted[l] - keysInverted[r]))
```

Comment: `comparator = null` — Это кто-то пошутил. Можно удалить его и оттуда, и из sort. + Сортировка не сработает для числовых ключей, и в браузерах, не поддерживающих ES6. Поэтому сортировка объектов - занятие неблагодарное. Нужен железобетонный порядок - используйте массив)

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME с чего бы? Это я адаптировал найденное так. Это работает. sort может принимать null (точнее вообще без компаратора работать) - тогда он сортирует просто по порядку.

Comment: Ну если вместо ключей `['a', 'b', 'c']` будет `[30, 20, 10]` и `{ 30: 'a', 20: 'b', 10: 'c' }` , то независимо от попыток сортировки, в объекте они всегда встанут в порядке возрастания `10, 20, 30`. + https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30076219/does-es6-introduce-a-well-defined-order-of-enumeration-for-object-properties

Comment: Хмм, странно. Я не понял почему так происходит.